# Remove Item from JList throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, jlist

NetBeans. UI created using IDE.
My implementation In order of appearance:

1 global form variable:

```
private DefaultListModel model;
```

2 constructor:

```
ArrayList<String> cameras = repository.getCameraNames();

model= new DefaultListModel();
for (int i = 0; i < cameras.size(); i++) {
    model.addElement(cameras.get(i));
}
thelist.setModel(model);
```

3 remove button:

```
private void btnRemoverActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int index = thelist.getSelectedIndex();

    model.removeElementAt(index);
}
```

On the removeElementAt line, I get NullPointerException. If i change the index for a explicit number, it works but doesn't with the index variable. But the selected index, doesn't work!

Anyone can help?

Oh, and here is some stackttrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FrmPrincipal.thelistValueChanged(FrmPrincipal.java:217)
at FrmPrincipal.access$000(FrmPrincipal.java:22)
at FrmPrincipal$1.valueChanged(FrmPrincipal.java:77)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:677)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.intervalRemoved(BasicListUI.java:2601)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.removeElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:332)
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed by changing the following method:

```
private void thelistValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    txtCameraName.setText(thelist.getSelectedValue().toString());
}
```

To

```
private void thelistValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    txtCameraName.setText((String)thelist.getSelectedValue());
}
```

But I don't know why!
Can someone explain why it didn't accept the toString() and accepted the casting?

Comment: This isn't a NPE out of the `JList`, but from a list selection listener. Have you looked at `FrmPrincipal`? Also, you'll want to check that `getSelectedIndex()` doesn't return `-1` (meaning nothing is selected) before calling `removeElementAt()`. Also, it is stated in the `removeElementAt(int)` javadoc that you should prefer `remove(int)` instead.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what NPE means. "thelist" is the name I gave to the IDE designed JList. getSelectedIndex() is returning the correct index. This is really weird.

Comment: NPE = `NullPointerException`. The NPE is coming from the list selection listener `FrmPrincipal.java:217` - start there.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Im not used to do Java stuff. Can you tell me how do I check the list selection listener of the FrmPrincipal? By the way, the form has two lists. The other one is unnused for now.

Comment: can you show the code of this method lstAverificarValueChanged

Comment: It is now there. I just translated the names to english. My variables are in portuguese.

Comment: I removed the whole thelistValueChanged implementation and now works! But I'm lacking an understanding of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your change "fixed" your problem because `getSelectedValue().toString()` will throw a NPE if there is no selection, whereas `(String)getSelectedValue()` will evaluate to `null` if there is no selection. But, if you ever put things in your list that aren't `String`s, then you'll get `ClassCastException`s when you try to cast the selected value to a `String`. So, this may have solved your current problem, but it's not a solution really.

I would just do this:

```
private void theListValueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    final Object selectedValue = theList.getSelectedValue();
    if ( selectedValue != null ) {
        txtCameraName.setText( selectedValue.toString() );
    } else {
        // Clear the text since there's no selection
        txtCameraName.setText( null );
    }   
}
```